# [ JAVA ]Reading one line with Scanner and store every entry in a String. Than read the scond line and do the same

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I've a CSV FIle with 2 lines of data. The first line is the heading and the second line is data associated with the heading. ( First heading = data from first heading ..etc.) I want to store each entry in a ArrayList. i want to use `;` and `"` as a `sc.useDelimiter`. This is my whole code:

```
public class CsvScanner {

private static Scanner sc;

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
String namesAdd;
String valuesAdd;


public void scanFile() {

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(Gui.selectedFile);
        sc.useDelimiter("[;\n]");

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            namesAdd = sc.nextLine();
            names.add(namesAdd);
            // System.out.println(names);
        }

        CreateLog.startLog();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    try {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            valuesAdd = sc.nextLine();
            values.add(valuesAdd);
            // System.out.println(values);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error v2");
    }
```

EDIT: i got it Running, but i cant make it stop on the END of the first line..

Comment: If you know your header only has one line, you do not need a while in your first block. Replace it by a if.

Comment: @StephaneM That line has 60 entrys

Comment: OK I did not read correclty. Do not try to read line and split at the same time. First read the line using your scanner, put it in a String, then split the String to get the 60 items. After that you can go on reading data.